# Problema com input java

Tags: java, input

Os inputs do meu programa estão se sobrescrevendo. Ele ignora o primeiro e ja lanca o segundo direto.

```
System.out.println("Digite o nome do passageiro");
String nome = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Digite o numero do ticket do passageiro");
int ticket = in.nextInt();
```

Como contornar este erro?

Comment: A variavel `in` é da classe `Scanner`?

Comment: Sim, essa mesmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque métodos como `nextInt`, e `next` não consomem a quebra de linha da entrada. Quando você chama `nextLine` o método encontra a quebra de linha e assume que a entrada é vazia.

Uma maneira de arrumar o problema é descartar a primeira quebra de linha antes de ler o nome:

```
in.nextLine();
String nome = in.nextLine();
```

Outra opção é mudar seu código para sempre usar `in.nextLine()` e fazer os *casts* manualmente, de forma que nunca sobre uma quebra de linha na entrada.

```
int ticket = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

---

**Referência**: [SOen - Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/664577)

Comment: Excelente isso mesmo :D